# How do I switch my Azure role to Windows Server 2008 R2 without explicitly specifying the version?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, azure-web-roles

[Azure service configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx) has two parameters - `osFamily` and `osVersion`. `osFamily` can be `1` to mean Windows Server 2008 (the default) or `2` to mean Windows Server 2008 R2. `osVersion` is `*` by default meaning "whatever, it's up to Azure infrastructure".

Now I want to switch from defaults to R2. I opened the configuration file and added `osFamily="2"` and now when I try to deploy the service I have the following error message:

> Invalid .cscfg file. If the osFamily attribute is set in the .cscfg file, you also need to set the osVersion attribute. The osVersion attribute can either be '*' for automatic operating system upgrades, or the name of a specific operating system version.

which somehow implies that now I have to specify the exact OS version.

I don't want to specify the exact version, I'd rather have "whatever, it's up to Azure, just let it be some Windows Server 2008 R2".

How do I switch to Windows 2008 R2 without explicitly specifying the exact OS version?

Comment: Was this an already deployed service?  I've tried to reproduce but couldn't get that error message.

Comment: @mcollier: I tried to both "upgrade" an existing deployment and create a new deployment - the behavior is the same for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you have a line in your .cscfg file that looks like this

```xml
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyService" osFamily="2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
```

Based on what the error message is telling you, while the `osVersion` may default to `*`, if you specify the `osFamily` you must also specify the `osVersion`.  In your case you want to add the attribute and set it to `*` as below.

```xml
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyService" osFamily="2" osVersion="*" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
```

Comment: This is just unbelievable. They really forced me to spell out the default value.

Comment: @sharptooth On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx it is listed as optional, and with `*` as default value so I understand the frustration, though, the error message did indicate that it's required if osFamily is set (in which case they want you to provide the value). Think the error was pretty clear personally, and so quite believable. Did you have any other issues when moving from osFamily `1` to osFamily `2`?

Comment: @jamiebarrow: Yeap, R2 doesn't like the password for the local user my code creates - thinks it's too simple.

Comment: @sharptooth maybe that's a good thing ;) Thanks for the update.